# A combinatorial sum and identity involving Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, analytic-number-theory, stirling-numbers, analytic-combinatorics

Let $n, k \geq 1$. Let $a(j),\, 1\leq j \leq k$, be a sequence of real numbers. Consider the sum
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k j! S(k, j) {n \choose j} a(j),
$$
where $S(k,j)$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind. Is there some kind of "inversion" identity that simplifies the sum? What is the sum in the simple case that $a(j) = 1$ for each $j$? Thanks.

**Update:** In the case when the $a(j) = 1$ the sum is well-known. It equals $n^k$. See [Marc van Leeuwen's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/519049/) in [abiessu's question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519004/does-this-sequence-of-inverse-binomial-numbers-have-a-name/), and Brian M. Scott's answer below. Any words on $a(j)$ arbitrary?

Comment: Please note this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/519049/86846 where my question was not the same as yours, but the identity seems to fairly closely match the sum you mention.

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems the sum is $n^k$ when the $a(j) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The expression has a simple combinatorial interpretation: for a fixed $j$ the expression $j!S(k,j)\binom{n}{j}$ is the number of functions from $[k]$ to $[n]$ whose range has cardinality $j$, so the sum is just the number of functions from $[k]$ to $[n]$, which is $n^k$.